# Capture the output of setup.py build_ext on stdout

Tags: python, cython, setup.py

In my current project, I'm extensively using Cython. I have many separated setup.py files to  build Cython code (*.pyx) with no issues at all, (python 3.8 and gcc 8.3) with the command:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Here is a straightforward example:

```
# =============================================================
#  Imports:
# =============================================================
import os
import sys
from distutils.core import setup
import setuptools
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import build_ext
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy
import os.path
import io
import shutil
# =============================================================
#  Modules:
# =============================================================
ext_modules = [
    Extension("cc1", ["cc1.pyx"],
        extra_compile_args=['-O3','-w','-fopenmp'],
        extra_link_args=['-fopenmp','-ffast-math','-march=native'],
        include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
        language='c++'),
    Extension("cc2", ["cc2.pyx"],
        extra_compile_args=['-O3','-w','-fopenmp'],
        extra_link_args=['-fopenmp','-ffast-math','-march=native'],
        include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
        language='c++'),
]
# =============================================================
#  Class:
# =============================================================
class BuildExt(build_ext):
    def build_extensions(self):
        if '-Wstrict-prototypes' in self.compiler.compiler_so:
            self.compiler.compiler_so.remove('-Wstrict-prototypes')
        super().build_extensions()
# =============================================================
#  Main:
# =============================================================
for e in ext_modules:
    e.cython_directives = {'embedsignature': True,'boundscheck': False,'wraparound': False,'linetrace': True, 'language_level': "3"}

setup(
    name='jackProject',
    version='0.1.0',
    author='Jack',
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': BuildExt},
    )
```

Everything works fine, and while the script is in execution, I can check the status on my console, as instance:

```
running build_ext
cythoning cc1.pyx to cc1.cpp
cythoning cc2.pyx to cc2.cpp
building 'cc1' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8

gcc -pthread -B /home/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c cc1.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/cc1.o -O3 -w -fopenmp
gcc -pthread -B /home/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c cc1.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/cc1.o -O3 -w -fopenmp
g++ -pthread -shared -B /home/anaconda3/compiler_compat -L/home/anaconda3/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/anaconda3/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/ build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/cc1.o -o /home/Desktop/DRAFT_CODING/Python/return_many_values_with_cyt/cc1.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -fopenmp -ffast-math -march=native

building 'cc2' extension
gcc -pthread -B /home/anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c cc2.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/cc2.o -O3 -w -fopenmp
g++ -pthread -shared -B /home/anaconda3/compiler_compat -L/home/anaconda3/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/anaconda3/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/ build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/cc2.o -o /home/Desktop/DRAFT_CODING/Python/return_many_values_with_cyt/cc2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -fopenmp -ffast-math -march=native
```

Now, that I have transferred my project into my Raspberry Pi 4, everything works fine as well, but when I start the setuptools, by launching the same command as usual on the remote terminal, for the same setup.py, this time nothing is written on the terminal, while the script is cythoninzing the source code.
Launch python with the 'verbose' option is not the best...
In this case my virtualenv is based on Python 3.9. with gcc 10.21.
Can anyone tell me what is happening or which is the culprit?
How can I capture again the classic output messages I have always seen until today?
It is not the end of the world, but it was convenient to follow the status of the execution, especially when creating many shared objects at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
```

instead of

```
from distutils.core import setup
...
from distutils.extension import Extension
```

cf. also https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#distutils-deprecated